# How to pre-process a very large data in python

Tags: python, machine-learning

I have a couple of files 100 MB each. The format for those files looks like this:

```
0  1  2  5  8  67  9  122
1  4  5  2  5  8
0  2  1  5  6
.....
```

(note the actual file does not have the alignment spaces added in, only one space separates each element, added alignment for aesthetic effect)

this first element in each row is it's *binary* classification, and the rest of the row are indices of features where the value is 1. For instance, the third row says the row's second, first, fifth and sixth features are 1, the rest are zeros.

I tried to read each line from each file, and use sparse.coo_matrix create a sparse matrix like this:

```
for train in train_files:  
    with open(train) as f:
        row = []
        col = []
        for index, line in enumerate(f):
            record = line.rstrip().split(' ')
            row = row+[index]*(len(record)-4)
            col = col+record[4:]
        row = np.array(row)
        col = np.array(col)
        data = np.array([1]*len(row))
        mtx = sparse.coo_matrix((data, (row, col)), shape=(n_row, max_feature))
        mmwrite(train+'trans',mtx)
```

but this took forever to finish. I started reading the data at night, and let the computer run after I went to sleep, and when I woke up, it still haven't finish the first file!

What are the better ways to process this kind of data?

Comment: `n_row  == 30000 == 0` is never going to become true.

Comment: ha! my bad. I added that to do some checking. I commented that out when I really run the code

Comment: What's your goal/purpose after you get the sparse matrix?

Comment: You can consider multiprocessing if memory is not an issue https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html

Comment: @Chih-HsuJackLin  I want to feed the matrix as features to train some models like svm, random forest ...etc

Comment: @Chih-HsuJackLin  ok, I'll check that out! thx

Comment: Is your expected result a matrix with rows as samples and columns as features?

Comment: Do you know the total feature number and total sample number in advance?

Comment: @Chih-HsuJackLin yes. I run a program first to get the max of all indices, and it is 136. each file contains about 1,600,000 rows, and I have about 15 of them.

I expected the result to be a sparse matrix that can be transformed into dense matrix with rows as samples and columns as features

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be a bit faster than your method because it does not read file line by line. You can try this code with a small portion of one file and compare with your code.
This code also requires to know the feature number in advance. If we don't know the feature number, it would require another line of code which was commented out.

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.sparse import lil_matrix
from functools import partial


def writeMx(result, row):
    # zero-based matrix requires the feature number minus 1
    col_ind = row.dropna().values - 1
    # Assign values without duplicating row index and values
    result[row.name, col_ind] = 1


def fileToMx(f):
    # number of features
    col_n = 136
    df = pd.read_csv(f, names=list(range(0,col_n+2)),sep=' ')
    # This is the label of the binary classification
    label = df.pop(0)
    # Or get the feature number by the line below
    # But it would not be the same across different files
    # col_n = df.max().max()
    # Number of row
    row_n = len(label)
    # Generate feature matrix for one file
    result = lil_matrix((row_n, col_n))
    # Save features in matrix
    # DataFrame.apply() is usually faster than normal looping
    df.apply(partial(writeMx, result), axis=0)
    return(result)

for train in train_files:
    # result is the sparse matrix you can further save or use
    result = fileToMx(train)
    print(result.shape, result.nnz)
    # The shape of matrix and number of nonzero values
    # ((420, 136), 15)
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

Your code were very helpful, but i couldn't use
　　　　df = pd.read_csv(f, sep=" ", header=None)
since each row has different lengths.

I finally got why it takes forever to run my code. It's because each time I append a list to the pre-existing list, it has to allocate a new memory space for the list. Hence as the list gets bigger and bigger, it takes longer and longer to do so. I work around this by allocate a fixed and big memory for the matrix, and it works just fun. Done in just a few seconds.

Thank you for your advices!

Comment: @I-PINGOu Good to hear you made it work. Good catch! I fixed it. The code should work now.